# jqGrid sortableRows and disableSelection in FireFox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jqGrid with the sortableRows option.
I also use inline editing of rows once rows are added to the grid.
It's working for me OK in Chrome, but then I tried it in FireFox and I find that inline editing doesn't work.  Clicks on any of the editable grid cells are ignored.

I traced the problem down to the fact that on mousedown event clicks happen with grid cells that the handler ui-disableSelection gets called in Firefox (but not in Chrome).  As a test, I forced the ui-disableSelection handler to not be called on mousedown click over a cell, and then inline editing works as expected.

Based on that, I searched and found that something like this problem has been reported in jQuery  (I'm using version 1.6.2):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-sortable-disableselection-firefox-issue-with-inputs

[jqueryUI Sortable: handling .disableSelection() on form inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027158/jqueryui-sortable-handling-disableselection-on-form-inputs)

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4429

The last two posts offer some possible solutions.  But I'm not clear in what exactly to change.

It sounds like the call to disableSelection() is deprecated and not recommended to be used.

The jqGrid.src.js file has the following code in it:

```
sortableRows : function (opts) {
    // Can accept all sortable options and events
    return this.each(function(){
    ......

            $("tbody:first",$t).sortable(opts);
            $("tbody:first",$t).disableSelection();
        }
    });
```

Based on the comments, I think the problem is the use of disableSelection() here.

I tried changing this to:

```
            $("tbody:first",$t).sortable(opts);
            $("tbody:first",$t).disableSelection();
            $("tbody:first",$t).find("input").enableSelect();
```

But that seems to introduce more problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into the same problem. There are several topics on this around the net:

[I can't type to inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083009/i-cant-type-to-inputs)

[UI Sortable | can't click input fields in Firefox if input field is in sortable element](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-sortable-can-t-click-input-fields-in-firefox-if-input-field-is-in-sortable-element)

An alternative would be to use something like [X-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) to remove the inputs from the table altogether.

Comment: OK.  I've just removed the disableSelection() call in jqGrid code and that seems to fix it.  I should have tried it earlier, but I thought doing so would break the sortableRows option.

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked for you. You have to love testing functionality for every browser in creation.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I run into the same problem today and thanks to this post I just found a solution based on one of the referenced links

[jqueryUI Sortable: handling .disableSelection() on form inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027158/jqueryui-sortable-handling-disableselection-on-form-inputs)

the final code would be something like:

```
$.fn.extend({
    preventDisableSelection: function(){
        return this.each(function(i) {
            $(this).bind('mousedown.ui-disableSelection selectstart.ui-disableSelection', function(e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });
        });
    }
});    

grid = $('#list');
grid.jqGrid({
   ...
   ondblClickRow: function (id) {
    if(id && id!==lastsel) {
        grid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
        lastsel=id; 
    }

    grid.jqGrid('editRow',id,true);

    // This is the relevant line        
    grid.find("input").preventDisableSelection();
}
   ...
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid',settings.pager,{edit:false,add:false,del:true});
grid.jqGrid('inlineNav',settings.pager, {
    addParams: {
        position:'last', 
        addRowParams: {keys: true}
    }, 
    editParams: {keys: true}
});
grid.jqGrid('sortableRows');
```

...

This code is slaghtly diferent from my actual one because I'm using several grids in the same page so I'm using general reusable code that would be not that clear for this situation.